# Responsive menu closes quickly in the main page

Tags: php, css, wordpress, menu, responsive

I have an issue with Responsive menu, when I click on the menu it open and closes quickly, but this just happen in the main menu, because in the other pages it doesn’t happen. All the pages takes the same menu.php, I restored a backup menu.php file and happens the same thing, I also restored the homepage.php and the header.php and nothing changes, the same issue.

```
<?php /* Template Name: Home Page */ ?>

<?php include ( TEMPLATEPATH . '/header.php'); ?>
<?php include ( TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/nav/menu-sup.php'); ?>
<?php include ( TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/varios/quick-contact.php'); ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php include ( TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/home/slider.php'); ?>
            <div align="center">
    <a href="http://page.org/page/" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.page.org/wp-content/themes/page/images/22.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="http://pagecalendar" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.page.org/wp-content/themes/page/images/portal31.png" /></a>  
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pg/page.org/photos/?tab=album&album_id=168951596363636788" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.page.org/wp-content/themes/page/images/GOLF.png" /></a>
    <!--<a href="http://page.org/padel" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.page.org/wp-content/themes/page/images/PADELRESP.gif" /></a>-->
    <a href="http://page.org/no-category/forjm/#anchor/" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.page.org/wp-content/themes/page/images/bannerweb2.png" /></a>

</div>
            <?php include ( TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/intros/home-intro.php'); ?>
            <?php include ( TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/home/colaborate.php'); ?>
            <div align="center">
       <a href="http://www.radio.com" target="_blank"> <img src="http://www.page.org/wp-content/themes/page/images/radio3mobile.png" /></a>
      <!-- <a href="http://www.page.org/document_oficials/N1 Magazine.pdf" target="_blank"> <img src="http://www.page.org/wp-content/themes/page/images/magazinemobile.jpg" /></a>-->
      <a href="http://page.org/magazine/" target="_blank"> <img src="http://www.page.org/wp-content/themes/page/images/magazinemobile.jpg" /></a>
</div>
            <?php include ( TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/home/loop-news.php'); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php else: ?>
        <?php include ( TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/vars/loop-void.php'); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <!--<?php include ( TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/home/newsletter.php'); ?>-->

<?php include ( TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/nav/menu-inf.php'); ?>  
<?php include ( TEMPLATEPATH . '/footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Please provide more detail like jsfiddle or codepane.

Comment: @JoykalInfotech I could provide the .js file, but there are 90000 characters. Also if you want I could provide a part of the .css file.

Comment: No one can help you without proper detail. So, please provide jsfiddle or codepane

Comment: @JoykalInfotech allright here i let you the .css:.                      `header-main { padding: 25px 20px 20px 20px; }
    .header-main .menu-trigger { display: block; float: left; width: 26px; height: 19px; background: url('../images/icons/menu.png') top center no-repeat; 
        background-size: contain; text-indent: -999999999px; overflow: hidden; margin-top: 5px; }
    .header-main .logo { display: block; float: right; width: 50%; height: 60px; background: url('../images/logo.png') top right no-repeat; 
        background-size: contain; text-indent: -999999999px; overflow: hidden; }`

Comment: @JoykalInfotech this is the other part css: `.menu-collapse-header { background: #464749; float: left; width: 100%; display: none; }
    .menu-collapse-header ul li a { background: #464749; color: #fff; padding: 15px; display: block; border-left: 8px solid #464749; }
    .menu-collapse-header ul li.current_page_item a { background: #57585a; border-left: 8px solid #57585a; }
    .menu-collapse-header ul li.current_page_ancestor a { background: #57585a; border-left: 8px solid #57585a; }
    .menu-collapse-header ul li a:hover {  background: #57585a; }`